# BeautifulSoup with Python to get articleBody

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

the idea is to extract the content found in articleBody but the code doesn't work for me. What am I missing to bring the note?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = 'https://www.clarin.com/sociedad/coronavirus-estudio-dice-acciones-sencillas-podrian-efectivas-cuarentenas_0_ZQM2_GZZn.html'
response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

label = soup.find("application/ld+json", text="articleBody:")
label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the data using `type="application/ld+json"`.

The data your looking at is in JSON format, you can convert it to a python dictionary using the `json` module:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.clarin.com/sociedad/coronavirus-estudio-dice-acciones-sencillas-podrian-efectivas-cuarentenas_0_ZQM2_GZZn.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")

json_data = json.loads(soup.find(type="application/ld+json").string)

print(type(json_data))
print(json_data['description'])
```

Output:

```
<class 'dict'>
Un equipo de investigadores de la Universidad de Viena, .....
```

---

Or you can use a CSS Selector to search for all `<p>` tags under the class `body-nota`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select(".body-nota > p"):
    print(tag.text)
```